# How to create java code to enter a string one letter by one letter then reversing?

Tags: java

create java code that asks the user to enter a word. this word is then outputted in this format:
Eg;

```
word is mummy
outputted like this:
m
mu
mum
mumm
mummy
mumm
mum
mu
m
```

This is what ive got so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class java
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      System.out.println("please enter a word");
      Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
      String word=kb.nextLine();
      int wordd=word.length();
      for(int i=1;i<=wordd;i++)
      {
         System.out.println(word.charAt(i));
      }
   }
}
```

My teacher said I need to use the java substring() method but I don't know how

Comment: Have you read the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) for `String.subString`?

Comment: Whatever IDE you're using it should tell you information about a method when you hover over it(which is the same information from the javadocs)

Comment: I removed the confusing comment about the semicolon: not to have a semicolon before the for block is absolutely normal.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("please enter a word");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = kb.nextLine();
        int wordd = word.length();
        for (int i = 1; i <= wordd; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(word.substring(0,i)); //print substring from 0 to i-1
        }
        for (int i = wordd-1    ; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            System.out.println(word.substring(0,i)); ////print substring from 0 to i-1
        }
    }
}
```

When you do substring there are  two index you provide. first is begin index and second is end index. Here if you take example of word mummy when we say substring (0,1) means start from 0 index and return 1-0=1 char that why its return 'm', then you say substring(0,2) means start from 0 index and return 2-0=2 char that is 'mu' and so on...
Always remember first parameter is begin index from where to begin and second is end index, however to get return value used (end - begin ) index.

Read java doc to understand different variants of substring.

Comment: This works after I added import java.util.Scanner; at the start. Thanks! :)

Comment: could someone please explain what the second part of the code does and how it works? java newbie here.for (int i = wordd-1    ; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            System.out.println(word.substring(0,i));

Comment: The part where it says for(int I=word-1;i>=0;i--)

Comment: It just reverse the ' i ' value as used in first loop

Comment: i think i got it now. the i-- is so that it displays 1 less letter each time because i is part of the substring

Comment: @EthanHunt It's not nice to give away the complete solution. Beginners should get a habit of understanding from the documentation. [Read this.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this :    

 public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("please enter a word");
            Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
            String word=kb.nextLine();
            int wordd=word.length();

            for(int i=1;i<wordd+1;i++){
                System.out.println(word.substring(0,i));
            }
            for(int i=wordd-1;i>=1;i--){
                System.out.println(word.substring(0,i));
            }

            kb.close();

            }
```

Comment: how would I do it the other way too and can you explain this whole substring method

Comment: Substring has a start index and an end index. 0 is considered the starting index for all arrays.  So what we are meaning by word.substring(0,i) is that take the substring of the 'word' that starts from 0th position till the 'i'th position.

Comment: ive read the java docs, the instructor wasn't clear on how to use substring. I get how to use the substring now but how would I reverse it? I'm thinking something like reversing the string variable but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: use a second for loop      
  for(int i=wordd-1;i>=1;i--){
      System.out.println(word.substring(0,i));
  }

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
public class azeemm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("please enter a word");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = kb.nextLine();
        int wordd = word.length();
        for (int i = 0; i <= wordd; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(word.substring(0,i));
        }
        for (int i = wordd-1    ; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            System.out.println(word.substring(0,i));
        }
    }
}

Comment: The complete code will be as :::   
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("please enter a word");
  Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
  String word=kb.nextLine();
  int wordd=word.length();
  
  for(int i=1;i<wordd+1;i++){
      System.out.println(word.substring(0,i));
  }
  for(int i=wordd-1;i>=1;i--){
      System.out.println(word.substring(0,i));
  }
  
  kb.close();
  
  }

 }

Comment: could you explain the part of the code where it says;for(int I=word-1;i>=0;i--)

Comment: for(int i=wordd-1;i>=1;i--)   means start from the length of word minus 1 and go on decreasing till its 1.